# Determine overlapping elements order

Tags: html, gwt, dom, drag-and-drop, z-index

i'm working with gwt and gwt-dnd ( a wonderful library for drag and drop).

I have a dropTarget ( a div) that overlap with another one, and the library pick the one under for the drop operation.
The reason is that the choise is done with the following criteria:

> Determines which DropController represents the deepest DOM descendant
>   drop target located at the provided location `(x, y)`.

which is right for descending DropTargets, but isn't for a hierarchy like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="a">
        <div id="b">
            <div id="c">
                <div id="DropTarget_D"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="1" style="position:absolute; z-index: 1; top:0; left:0">
         <div id="DropTarget_2"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rxwMB/

As you can see from code (at the end of the post), in this case DropTarget_C is used (as it is the "deepest") even if DropTarget_2 is displayed over.

**How can i tell, given two components, which one is the topmost one ?**

here's the code that make the choise:

```
private int compareElement(Element myElement, Element otherElement) {
  if (myElement == otherElement) {
    return 0;
  } else if (DOM.isOrHasChild(myElement, otherElement)) {
    return -1;
  } else if (DOM.isOrHasChild(otherElement, myElement)) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    // check parent ensuring global candidate sorting is correct
    Element myParentElement = myElement.getParentElement().cast();
    Element otherParentElement = otherElement.getParentElement().cast();
    if (myParentElement != null && otherParentElement != null) {
      return compareElement(myParentElement, otherParentElement);
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

The dropTarget is picked from a ordered list whose was ordered using this function.
If the list contains only DropTarget_D and DropTarget_2 and both meet the conditions, the first one is picked (even if it's covered by DropTarget_2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

(for gwt-dnd : https://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/issues/detail?id=169 )

```
package com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.client;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.client.DropControllerCollection.Candidate;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class OverlappingDropTargetsHandler {

    private static class StackingContext{
        private Element element;
        private LinkedList<Object> childrens;

        public StackingContext(Element element) {
            if(element == null){
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
            this.element = element;
            this.childrens = new LinkedList<Object>();
        }

        public Element getElement() {
            return element;
        }

        public void addChildren(Candidate candidate) {
            this.childrens.add(candidate);
        }

        public void addChildren(StackingContext stackingContext) {
            this.childrens.add(stackingContext);            
        }

        public LinkedList<Object> getChildrens() {
            return this.childrens;
        }

        public int getZIndex(){
            return this.element.getPropertyInt("z-index");
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return element.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if(obj instanceof StackingContext){
                return this.element.equals(((StackingContext)obj).element);
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void sort(Candidate[] candidates) {       
        HashMap<Element, OverlappingDropTargetsHandler.StackingContext> cache = new HashMap<Element, OverlappingDropTargetsHandler.StackingContext>();

        initStackingContextsList(candidates, cache);

        StackingContext rootStackingContext = resolveStackingContextsHierarcy(cache);

        cache = null; //non mi serve piu

        assert rootStackingContext != null;

        Comparator<Object> comparator = new Comparator<Object>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object a, Object b) {
                assert a instanceof StackingContext || a instanceof Candidate;
                assert b instanceof StackingContext || b instanceof Candidate;

                boolean aInstanceOfStackingContext = a instanceof StackingContext;
                boolean bInstanceOfStackingContext = b instanceof StackingContext;

                if(aInstanceOfStackingContext && bInstanceOfStackingContext){
                    int ai = ((StackingContext)a).getZIndex();
                    int bi = ((StackingContext)b).getZIndex();
                    if(ai<bi){  return -1;
                    }else if(ai>bi){  return 1;
                    }else{  return 0;}
                }else if(aInstanceOfStackingContext && !bInstanceOfStackingContext){
                    return ((StackingContext)a).getZIndex()<0? -1: 1;
                }else if(!aInstanceOfStackingContext && bInstanceOfStackingContext){
                    return ((StackingContext)b).getZIndex()<0? 1: -1;
                }else /* if(!aInstanceOfStackingContext && !bInstanceOfStackingContext) */{
                    return ((Candidate)a).compareTo((Candidate)b);
                }
            }           
        };

        Queue<Object> queue = new LinkedList<Object>();
        queue.add(rootStackingContext);
        Object o;
        int i = 0;
        while((o = queue.poll()) != null){
            if(o instanceof StackingContext){
                Collections.sort(((StackingContext)o).getChildrens(), comparator);
                //reverse iterator
                ListIterator<Object> it = ((StackingContext)o).getChildrens().listIterator(((StackingContext)o).getChildrens().size());
                while(it.hasPrevious()){
                    queue.offer(it.previous());
                }
            }else /* if(o instanceof Candidate) */{
                candidates[i++] = (Candidate)o;
            }
        }

//      if(DOMUtil.DEBUG == true){
//          printTree(rootStackingContext, 0);      
//          printArray(candidates);
//      }
    }

    private static void initStackingContextsList(Candidate[] candidates, HashMap<Element, OverlappingDropTargetsHandler.StackingContext> cache){
        for(Candidate candidate : candidates) {
            Element stackingContextElement = findNearestStackingContextParentElement(candidate.getDropTarget().getElement());
            if(stackingContextElement != null){
                StackingContext stackingContext = cache.get(stackingContextElement);
                if(stackingContext == null){
                    stackingContext = new StackingContext(stackingContextElement);
                    cache.put(stackingContextElement, stackingContext);
                }
                stackingContext.addChildren(candidate);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param cache
     * @return the root StackingContext
     */
    private static StackingContext resolveStackingContextsHierarcy(HashMap<Element, OverlappingDropTargetsHandler.StackingContext> cache) {
        Queue<StackingContext> queue = new LinkedList<OverlappingDropTargetsHandler.StackingContext>(cache.values());

        StackingContext stackingContext;
        StackingContext rootStackingContext = null;
        while((stackingContext = queue.poll()) != null){
            Element parentElement = findNearestStackingContextParentElement(stackingContext.getElement());
            if(parentElement != null){
                StackingContext parentStackingContext = cache.get(parentElement);
                if(parentStackingContext == null){
                    parentStackingContext = new StackingContext(parentElement);
                    cache.put(parentElement, parentStackingContext);
                    queue.offer(parentStackingContext);
                }
                parentStackingContext.addChildren(stackingContext);
            }else{
                //this stackingContext is the root
                assert rootStackingContext == null || rootStackingContext == stackingContext;
                rootStackingContext = stackingContext;
            }
        }

        return rootStackingContext;
    }

    /**
     * @param element
     * @return the first parent that create a StackingContext or null if element is the root
     */
    private static Element findNearestStackingContextParentElement(Element element) {
        assert element != null;
        Element parentElement = element;
        while((parentElement = parentElement.getParentElement()) != null){
//          if(DOMUtil.DEBUG == true){
//              parentElement.getStyle().setProperty("border", "2px solid " + "orange");
//          }
            if(isStackingContext(parentElement)){
                return parentElement;
            }
//          if(DOMUtil.DEBUG == true){
//              parentElement.getStyle().setProperty("border", "2px solid " + "white");
//          }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static native String getComputedProperty(Element e, String property)  /*-{
        return window.getComputedStyle(e).getPropertyValue(property);
     }-*/;  

    private static boolean isStackingContext(Element element) {
        String position = getComputedProperty(element, "position");
        String zindex = getComputedProperty(element, "z-index");

         if((!position.equals("static")) && (!zindex.equals("") && !zindex.equals("0"))){
            return true;
        }else if(RootPanel.get().getElement() == element){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        //TODO: gestire gli altri casi in cui viene creata un stacking context:

//      The root element always holds a root stacking context.
//
//      Setting z-index to anything other than 1 on an element that is positioned (i.e. an element with position that isn't static).
//
//      Note that this behavior is slated to be changed for elements with position: fixed such that they will always establish stacking contexts regardless of their z-index value. Some browsers have begun to adopt this behavior, however the change has not been reflected in either CSS2.1 or the new CSS Positioned Layout Module yet, so it may not be wise to rely on this behavior for now.
//
//      This change in behavior is explored in another answer of mine, which in turn links to this article and this set of CSSWG telecon minutes.
//
//      Another exception to this is with a flex item. Setting z-index on a flex item will always cause it to establish a stacking context even if it isn't positioned.
//
//      Setting opacity to anything less than 1.
//
//      Transforming the element:
//
//      Setting transform to anything other than none.
//
//      Setting transform-style to preserve-3d.
//
//      Setting perspective to anything other than none.
//
//      Creating a CSS region: setting flow-from to anything other than none on an element whose content is anything other than normal.
//
//      In paged media, each page-margin box establishes its own stacking context.
    }

    private static void printTree(StackingContext stackingContext, int level){  

        String s = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
            s += "_";
        }

        for(Object o : stackingContext.getChildrens()){
            if(o instanceof StackingContext){
                Logger.getLogger("test").log(Level.WARNING, s + "(s) "+((StackingContext)o).getElement().getClassName()+" z-index="+ ((StackingContext)o).getZIndex());
                printTree((StackingContext)o, level+1);
            }else /* if(o instanceof Candidate) */{
                Logger.getLogger("test").log(Level.WARNING, s + "(c) "+((Candidate)o).getDropTarget().getElement().getClassName());
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printArray(Candidate[] candidates) {
        String s = "[";
        for(int i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++) {
            s+=candidates[i].getDropTarget().getElement().getNodeName();
            if(i < candidates.length-1){
                s += ", ";
            }
        }
        Logger.getLogger("test").log(Level.WARNING, s +"]");
    }
}
```